# BEM element and block on the same DOM node

Tags: css, bem

Is it correct to use element and block classnames on the same DOM node as in the example below?

```
<div class="b-panel">
   <div class="b-panel__head"></div>
   <div class="b-panel__body"></div>

   <!-- b-nav is an individual block but also element of b-panel -->

   <div class="b-nav b-panel__nav">
      <a href="#" class="b-nav__prev">Prev</a>
      <span class="b-nav__label">Label</span>
      <a href="#" class="b-nav__next">Next</a>
   </div>

</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a **mix**:

> You can also mix an element with a block using BEMHTML templates of a block. Let's specify that each item element from a goods block has the same formatting as a head block. For this you need to mix each item from a goods block with a box block from j library. *[source: [a tutorial from bem.info](http://bem.info/tutorials/start-with-project-stub/#Mix-of-blocks-and-elements)]*

In your code:

```
<div class="b-panel">
   <div class="b-nav b-panel__nav"></div>
</div>
```

The inner DOM element is a mix of the block `b-nav` and the element `b-panel__nav`.